# MS-Access Add Additional Linked Tables

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-migration-assi, linked-tables

I have an MS-Access database that was converted to use SQL Tables using the "Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for Access" (aka SSMA) and created linked tables (so the MS-Access interface still works but is linked to SQL Tables).

Modifying those tables has been no problem (modify in SQL, use the Linked Table Manager in MS-Access, update tables).  But I've not added a new table in SQL and I can't find a way to add that table to the set of linked tables.

I've tried the External Data -> ODBC Database, but it wants me to make a FileDSN and since the SSMA tool didn't require that I don't want to have some tables linked one way and other files liked another way (does anyone know how SSMA links the tables?).

So my underlying question is:  Without using DSN how do I add an additional SQL Server table to MS-Access as a linked table?

Comment: There is only one "way" that tables are linked. Doesn't matter how you get there, the resulting object is a link. If you don't want to use a DSN you can add the links with VBA.